# What type of object is a opencv::Mat? It is a shared_ptr or maybe an auto_ptr ? is it a pointer?

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, stl, smart-pointers

I used OpenCv and I used it in code similar to the following code:

```
Mat Create()
{ 
     Mat myMat(10, 10, CV8U_C1);    
     int x=myMat.Rows; // I am accessing Mat like an object not a pointer. 
     Return myMat;
 }

 Main()
 {
       Mat aMat=Create(); // created inside this function
       int x=aMat.Rows; // accessing it using . notation
       // do some work
       return;   //I did not delete Mat, as it would release its memory.
 }
```

How can  create similar objects n my c++ code?

I am using STL, but if needed I can use Boost too.

Comment: `aMat` would still be destroyed. (RAII idiom)

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Thanks I know. My question is how Mat is defined? Is it a shared_pointer? As I am accesing it using . , it can not be a pointer. then what is it?

Comment: @mans It's just a normal class. Like this: `class Mat { };`

Comment: @H2CO3 so when I pass it from one function into other, it is copied over? That would be very inefficient and opencv should be very slow.

Comment: @JBL what is then? A normal class?

Comment: @mans No, it is not copied. In this class the data is shared across copies of the object. Every new copy just assigns the data pointer internally but does not deep copy the image.

Comment: @Kourosh So who will delete the internal data?

Comment: @mans Don't worry about efficiency yet. You're not at the level of experience that would give you the right to.

Comment: @H2CO3 You maybe right that I am not experience, but I am sure that there is a trick in defining Mat that makes it efficient. I am looking to learn that trick!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `std::vector`, `Mat`, and other data structures have destructors that deallocate the underlying memory buffers when needed. This means that the destructors do not always deallocate the buffers as in case of `Mat`. They take into account possible data sharing. A destructor decrements the reference counter associated with the matrix data buffer. The buffer is deallocated **if and only if** the reference counter reaches zero. That is, when no other structures refer to the same buffer. Similarly, when a `Mat` instance is copied, no actual data is really copied. Instead, the reference counter is incremented to memorize that there is another owner of the same data. There is also the `Mat::clone()` method that creates a full copy of the matrix data.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to write a base class that when my class is inherited from it, it do the reference counting for me and call a virtual function in a way that I can release memories that I allocated?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct -- `cv::Mat` is a resource-owning object like `std::vector<>` that can be passed around and returned by value. However, there is one very important way in which `cv::Mat` behaves like a pointer, and that's in regards to its aliasing behavior. For most types `T`, the following is true:

```
T orig = initial_value;
T copy = orig;
mutate(copy);
assert(orig == initial_value);
```

That is, for most types, copies are independent. You can mutate one without affecting the other. **This is not true for `cv::Mat`.** Instead, you have to watch out for stuff like this:

```
cv::Mat orig = /* ... matrix of all zeros ... */
cv::Mat copy = orig; // NOTE! Creates an alias, not a copy.
copy(2,2) = 42;
assert(orig(2,2) == 42); // Huh.
```

See? changing the copy changed the original. Speaking technically, `cv::Mat` is not a *regular type*, which is a pity because most modern APIs including the STL assume that types are regular. With `cv::Mat`, things silently alias, leading to hard-to-find, spooky-action-at-a-distance kinds of bugs. Use `cv::Mat` with *extreme* care. And not ever with STL algorithms and containers.

Comment: Thanks for this heads up, I was wondering about exactly this. Is there a way to find out which operations on `cv::Mat` cause it to be copied?

Comment: Pass and return a `vector<T>` by value is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered by just a quick look at the [API reference](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)

```
class CV_EXPORTS Mat
{
public:
    // ... a lot of methods ...
    ...
```

The best thing to do would be to read the [OpenCV tutorial on Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html)

> The first thing you need to know about Mat is that you no longer need to manually allocate its memory and release it as soon as you do not need it. ...
>
> Mat is basically a class with two data parts: the matrix header (containing information such as the size of the matrix, the method used for storing, at which address is the matrix stored, and so on) and a pointer to the matrix containing the pixel values ...